# Algorithm for calculating the specific space inside the column chart

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph, charts

I am writing an algorithm to calculate the space given in a column chart. The algorithm is in Python. The algorithm is as follows: Enter a series of numbers (for example: 1 2 6 5 9 23 1) separated by a space. These numbers indicate the height of each column in the column chart and the length of each column is equal to 1. If we assume these columns in such a way that if we pour water on them, the water will only exit from the left and right sides, the program should output the amount of remaining water. Look at the image below for a better understanding.
[image]
[image: Water does not collect]
[image]
[image]

**Sample input**

```
4 1 3 5 2 3 4
```

**Sample output**

```
7
```

There are many **special cases** for this question and so far I have not been able to write an algorithm in Python that can answer all special cases. Can anyone write this algorithm in python **without using libraries?**

If you can explain with the code you write or draw a flowchart so that I can understand.

Comment: is the water pouring from a specific point, or is it just the case that it fills everywhere?

Comment: Water only comes out from the left and right side. For example, in the above figures you can see several states of water accumulation, but in the lower right figure, no water remains(I have given you the shape of another special mode).

Comment: I don't know if you follow. What I mean to say is, whereabouts is the "tap", if anywhere? Does it have a fixed location?

Comment: also, would you be able to share some of the "special cases"? I have a version which works on the examples in the question, but I'm obviously in the dark about those

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't understand. Suppose it is rain water that collects. It rains in all the charts but it accumulates in certain places.

Comment: The diagrams I posted can be enough to understand the question, but for your better understanding, I am uploading the diagram of the states that may be ignored. With thanks for your attention.

Comment: similar kind of problem: https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/17